PHP 8.3.8 build error "recompile with -fPIE and relink with -pie" on AlmaLinux
I am trying to build a custom configured php-8.3.8 (pulled from Git) on
AlmaLinux 8.10 (formerly CentOS, RHEL-compatible).
I am stuck on the following error:
/bin/sh /temp/php-src-php-8.3.8/libtool --silent --preserve-dup-deps 
--tag=CC --mode=link cc -export-dynamic -fno-common -Wformat-truncation 
-Wlogical-op -Wduplicated-cond -Wno-clobbered -Wall -Wextra 
-Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-compare -g -O2 -ffp-contract=off 
-fvisibility=hidden -pthread -Wimplicit-fallthrough=1 -DZTS 
-DZEND_SIGNALS -DZEND_MAX_EXECUTION_TIMERS   
-Wl,-zcommon-page-size=2097152 -Wl,-zmax-page-size=2097152 -no-pie 
-no-pie  ext/date/php_date.o /...OMMITTED FOR BREVITY.../ 
sapi/cli/ps_title.o sapi/cli/php_cli_process_title.o -ltidy -lresolv 
-lrt -lutil -lrt -lm -ldl -lpthread -lxml2 -lssl -lcrypto -lsqlite3 -lz 
-lcurl -lxml2 -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lpng16 -lz -ljpeg -lfreetype -lonig 
-lsqlite3 -lxml2 -lxml2 -lxml2 -lxml2 -lxml2 -lzip -lz -lssl -lcrypto 
-lrt -o sapi/cli/php
/usr/bin/ld: dynamic STT_GNU_IFUNC symbol `mb_wchar_to_utf16le' with 
pointer equality in `ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_utf16.o' can 
not be used when making an executable; recompile with -fPIE and relink 
with -pie
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:297: sapi/cli/php] Error 1

I see the "-no-pie" option in the command line above, and the error
occurs even if I set the LDFLAGS=-no-pie environment variable per the
documentation here:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Position-Independent-Executable-PIE-Enabled-by-Default-on-Linux.html
However, I still can not get past the error.  Can anyone provide any
suggestions?
